# Azure Hyperscale Database Tier Row duplicate

Tags: azure-sql-database

I was working with another part of my code, while my web app started to have an error at duplicate entry in the dictionary.

I've looked into Azure Database via SQL Management Studio, opened tabled and saw for TWO equal entries.

This happened second time. First time i've thought that happened something with me...

But now this happened again. Azure SQL Hyperscale: Gen4, 1 vCore duplicated my row.

SQL Memory Optimized = True

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to provide some details about your database (database name, server name)? Could you also open a support ticket with us, so that we can work closely with you on resolving this issue? You can open a ticket through your azure portal.

Comment: Thanks ShreyaVerma the database doesn't exist yet, conceptually we're looking to understand if we can do private networking with the Hyperscale citus database